# How to verify a top level function was called with Mockk?

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

How to verify that a top level (static) function was called in a test with MockK?

Simple approach like:

```
verify { someTopLevelFunction("some text") }
```

results in `io.mockk.MockKException: can't find stub kotlin.Unit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would mockk the same way you mockk extension functions https://mockk.io/#extension-functions

In practice generally:

```
mockkStatic(ClassNameWhereFunctionIsLocated::class)

verify {
    someTopLevelFunction("some text")
}
```

Comment: Would like to add, just to avoid future bugs, that when mocking static functions you should in general call `unmockAll()` in the `@After` tear-down method of your tests, otherwise it will stay mocked between tests and even test classes (which is usually not what you want)

Comment: The problem ist there is no class, the function is top level. But even if I do mockkStatic(:: someTopLevelFunction) its not working.

Comment: @georgij on the JVM there is _always_ a class, even if the function is top-level. The class name is the file name followed by "Kt". See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#package-level-functions (as well as the link provided in this answer which also shows you how to mock a top-level function)

Comment: Ah, I need to replace this "pkg." with my full package, now I know.